Upgrade angular 11 to 17 gave errors
I have:

Angular CLI 17
Node: 18.20.2
Package Manager: npm 10.5.0

I have old project with version: 11
I have open it and run npm i thennpm audit fix --force
here I run ng v and got:

@angular-devkit/architect          0.1801.2
@angular-devkit/build-angular      18.1.2
@angular-devkit/core               18.1.2
@angular-devkit/schematics         18.1.2
@angular/cdk                       11.2.13
@angular/cli                       18.1.2
@angular/material                  11.2.13
@angular/material-moment-adapter   11.2.13
@schematics/angular                18.1.2
rxjs                               6.6.7
typescript                         4.0.8
zone.js                            0.10.3

after that I have tried to upgrade angular version to 17
So I started by run: ng update @angular/core@12 @angular/cli@12
but I got error
× Migration failed: Incompatible peer dependencies found.
Peer dependency warnings when installing dependencies means that those dependencies might not work correctly together.
You can use the '--force' option to ignore incompatible peer dependencies and instead address these warnings later.
See "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-UXBEuC\angular-errors.log" for further details.
how can solve this and upgrade to 17

Should I have to uninstall angular and node and everything related to angular, then install from angular 11 and related tools versions?

yes, and follow recommended  step by step upgrades here  https://angular.dev/update-guide (recommended to do one major version at a time, first 11 to 12, test, then 12 to 13, test , etc...

you might not have to reinstall node, but you should have that in a docker-ish container anyway.

how can I do upgrade in docker. why ?

why: because it's a covnenient way to set the versions of all libraries and tools without impacting those installed on the main machine. Especially important if you start to maintain / develop / execute two apps or more.

Try what the message says - you should update if using --force flag. After installing, you should be able to bump packages and everything should work

This is what I have now:
This version of CLI is only compatible with Angular versions ^18.0.0,
but Angular version 16.2.12 was found instead.

you need to globally update angular cli npm install -g @angular/cli

that's what I did.. try to update without force, if failed then add --force.. until got version17
